# Remove white spaces from a variable

Tags: linux, shell, whitespace

I want to remove the white spaces from a variable in Linux Shell and echo it on the terminal.
Following is my code:

```
echo "Enter your full name"
read fname
$fname | sed "s/ //g"
```

When I run the code it shows command not found.

Comment: Last command should be like this `echo $fname | sed "s/ /g"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just call a variable (think of it as just a string value container). You need to `echo` it:

```
echo $fname | sed "s/ //g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to echo $fname:

```
echo $fname | sed "s/ //g"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using bash

```
read -p "Enter your full name: " fname
echo "${fname// /}"
```

The form `${fname// /}` is an example of bash's *Pattern  substitution*.  It looks more generally like `${variablename//old/new}` and it finds all occurrences of the pattern `old` in `variablename` and replaces them with `new`.  In our case, `old` is a space and `new` is an empty string.

*Pattern substitution* is not required by POSIX and this will not work, for example, under `dash` (which is `/bin/sh` on debian-like systems).

#### Using any POSIX shell

```
read -p "Enter your full name: " fname
printf "%s" $fname
echo ""
```

#### Example

```
$ bash script
Enter your full name: Joe Bob Smith
JoeBobSmith
```

Comment: Note that this will work in bash but not dash (Debian/Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`) or POSIX shells in general.